# JSON Array to UITableView insert

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Hello I have one question, I have one json url and this json url is return bellow json content;

```
{"ROW”:2,”COLUMN”:[“Name”,”Surname”],"DATA”:{“Name”:[“your_name”,”your_name1”],“Surname”:[“your_surname”,”your_surname1”]}}
```

But for me is needed this json format to convert  Swift UITableView,  im tested SwiftyJson but is not worked correctly for my issue. Im created one array and UITableView and im inserted correctly this array to UITableView, but I don’t know how can i add  this json content to UITableView.
Thank you very much.

My Swift Code:

```
let animalArray = ["Firsname","Firsname","Firsname"]


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)-> Int{
    return animalArray.count

}



func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for:indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = animalArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This pseudo CSV structure defeats the efficiency of JSON decoding considerably. If you have any influence on the backend ask for sending more *JSON-ish* data.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment @vadian , but im not have access to editing this data from backend, for this you do you have any idea how to make parse this json content and to push UITableView, thanks

Comment: The structure implies that the number of columns and the keys are dynamic. So you have to decode the JSON *manually* with `JSONSerialization` and build an array of dictionaries. The relevant data is in the value for key `DATA`, the other key/value pairs are redundant.

Comment: thank you very much @vadian but for this example please do you write how can i retrive data to array from this json file.thanks

Comment: @Linuxman JSONSerialization gives you a dictionary. You write code to turn that dictionary into anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should first fetch JSON for example in viewDidLoad(), assign its values to some var or let declared in your view controller and then use it just the same way you just did.
[Guide to fetch and decode JSON](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwT2EyAVLmI)

Note your struct must be the exact copy of the JSON. Since it is

```
{ 
  "ROW”: 2,
  ”COLUMN”:[“Name”,”Surname”],
  "DATA”: { “Name”: [“your_name”,”your_name1”],
            “Surname”: [“your_surname”,”your_surname1”] }
}
```

your struct must be

```
struct JSONStruct: Codable {
    var ROW: Int
    var COLUMN: [String]
    var DATA: Dictionary<String: [String]>
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @Andery, but im writed this is not returned any data. My code is:      struct DATA : Decodable {
               let Firstname: String
           }
        let url = "MYURL"
        let urlObj = URL(string: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data,response,error) in
            do{
                var countries  = try JSONDecoder().decode([DATA].self, from: data!)
                for DATA in countries {
                    print (DATA.Firstname)
                }
            } catch {
            }
        }

Comment: Try using this tool to verify your JSON first: https://jsonlint.com

Comment: Yes is displayed Valid JSON

Comment: @Linuxman, it seems I know what the problem is. Have a look at my latest update.